# AngularJS scope is updated but the UI is not

Tags: angularjs, scope, intervals

I have some content populating in an ng-repeat when the page loads by setting $scope.questions and binding it. Then I'm using $interval to query the backend every few seconds to see if there are any updates - if there are I push the new data to $scope.questions.

This updates the UI, some of the time. If it starts working it will continue to do so. Most of the time though it is definitely updating $scope.questions but it isn't reflected in the UI. The intermittent nature of it makes me think it's a timing issue but I haven't been able to nail that down. Testing with the same exact actions doesn't yield consistent results.

The update is happening in scope - when I try to execute $apply or $digest I get an inproc error. $timeout doesn't seem to change anything. I'm really stuck here.

HTML

```
<div class="feedContainerDiv" ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp:true">
    <div class="feedName">{{question.name}}</div>
    <div class="feedTitle">{{question.title}}</div>
    <div class="feedQuestion>{{question.question}}</div>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
if (updateInterval > 0) {
uiMil = updateInterval * 1000;
$interval(function() {
    QuestionFactory.getNewQuestions()
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data[0] !== undefined) {
                var pushObject = new Object();
                for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    pushObject = response.data[i];
                    $scope.questions.push(pushObject);
                }
            }
        });
}, uiMil);
}
```

Comment: Why `var pushObject = new Object();` inside the "if"? I think just `var pushObject;` **before** the "if" is better. Anyway, this shouldn't affect your issue.

Comment: Does `getNewQuestions` **always** return a promise?

Comment: I had experienced something like this before. In my case, the scope was updated, but it was the wrong scope. Due to some refactoring, I caused my controller to get instantiated twice (using nested views w/ui-router). As such, the scope that the view was using was not the one being updated. You can log to the console in your controller's "startup" code to see if that's happening to you.

Comment: This seems like something that would be more suitable to be in a directive, and then use $compile to update it.

Comment: OMG, +1 @SunilD. I love you. I was updating the src of an iframe it was contained in, which instantiated the controller twice. That was right on the money. By the way, is that how I credit you with the plus one? I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @AbeHendlish Probably the best thing to do is for you to write an answer w/your exact solution (since I was just guessing). I suggested you write the answer in case you can add more relevant details. Either way, once there is an answer you can mark it as accepted (it's OK to accept your own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was reloading the context under certain conditions so it was creating a new scope each time I did that. I was trying to refer to $scope.questions expecting content which was being reloaded with stale content.

Always make sure you are working within the expected scope! That's the lesson I learned here.